# Derby invalid with encoding when connecti via jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I have a database in derby. When connect via `ij` everything seems to be ok (encoding is ok):

[image]

But when connect via JDBC:

```
public String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
public String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";

public void init() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Object dr = Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
}


public Connection getConnection(String dbName, String params) throws SQLException {
    String connCon = protocol + dbName + ";create=false";
    if (params != null) {
        connCon += "," + params;
    }
    return DriverManager.getConnection(connCon);
}
```

encoding is broken (missing special character for polish alphabet). What I do wrong?

EDIT:
My app is run on Tomcat server (nevest version, via Eclipse IDE) on Ubuntu Core (newest LTS)

Comment: Is your Java source file saved with UTF-8 encoding? I have seen strange behaviour with Unicode characters when the .java file was saved with cp1252 or some other non-Unicode encoding.

Comment: @GordThompson yeep, my source files are saved with UTF-8.

Comment: When you run your Java app does it display `ł` as `l`, as `?`, or is it omitted entirely? Also please [edit] your question to specify your environment: what OS, the IDE you are using (if any), and how you are running the app (e.g., from within your IDE, from the console, ...)

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying derby.ui.locale? https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/tools/rtoolsijlocale.html

Comment: @GordThompson it displays `?`. I've just edited my question - added some details about application running.

Comment: @BryanPendleton no, I will try that and then report.

Comment: @BryanPendleton specyifing local or territory didn't helped.

Comment: May you correct the typo in your title?

Comment: @Cœur hard to say. It was about 2,5 years ago, I don't remember what helped ;)

Comment: I mean, is _**connecti**_ a typo for _connect_, _connection_, _connecting_, ...?